# Lambda expression conversion in Java?

Tags: lambda

I have a code like this.How to convert it into lambda expression?

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: you seem not to understand what lambda is.

Comment: Hi  Marcin, Thanks a lot for quick response.I have bit idea.But I am surprise that such a common scenario why Lambda expression can not handle.I know I can define array and express it in Lambda. But I want to Handle this with Lambda expression.

Comment: Unfortunately Stackoverflow is neither tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can can help solve [certain on-topic problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to **[put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** on the subject in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://google.com/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide quite a simple example for using lambdas

But just for learning's sake, it can be rewritten in something like this:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(
    n -> { System.out.println(n); }
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for info.It works.I do not know How I miss this scenario while learning.